# How can I get and remove WebClient DownloadFileCompleted event subscribers?

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I made a simple download manager based on **WebClient**. somthing like this:

```
    public class DownloadManager(){

     public static Dictionary<string,WebClient> DownloadList{get;set;}
         //...
         
     public static WebClient CheckInProgressDownload(string key)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient result;

            if (DownloadsList.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            {
               
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
       
    }
```

By getting specific **WebClient** Object from *DownloadList* property I can show download progress in a dynamically created Progress Bar.
When I Create a new instance of progress bar  I have to subscribe to  **WebClient** *DownloadFileCompleted* and *DownloadProgressChanged* events.

```
 public calss ProgressConrolGroup(){
    
    public void OnCreate(){
    
       var wc = new DownloadManager.CheckInProgressDownload(stringkey);
       
      if(wc!=null){
              wc.DownloadProgressChanged += WC_DownloadProgressChanged;
       }
    
    }

private void WC_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender,System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
    progressbar.Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
     }
}
```

My Problem is as you see , every time I get Existing WebClient Object from list, It has Previously Event handler attached to it. how can I remove its event handlers and add new one?

**important note**: I saw some answer on stack overflow but none of them were useful to me. like this [Get compiler generated delegate for an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598644/get-compiler-generated-delegate-for-an-event/2598667) and this one [remove all EventHandlers of a specific Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773844/remove-all-eventhandlers-of-a-specific-control). and this example either :[How to remove all event handlers from an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event) .

Comment: Before `wc.DownloadProgressChanged += WC_DownloadProgressChanged;` add `wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= WC_DownloadProgressChanged;` ?

Comment: @dr.null I tried this too. even did it in a loop and remove handler multiple times. didn't work.

Comment: Excuse me. Are you using a single `ProgressBar` here? If that so, the `WC_DownloadProgressChanged` event will fire for each subscribed instance and update the progress with its own percentage. Either, sum the total download size and show the overall progress, or better use an `async` pattern to download a file from the queue and show its progress. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553778/14171304).